# SQLite ':'-style parameter substituion in Tcl API: why is this integer treated as string in condition?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I'm likely doing something stupid again but I don't understand the parameter substitution in the query below. The column `char_len` is declared as integer.

Tcl variable `selEnd` is substituted as a string, it appears, in the SQLite query because the query returns all the rows as if the condition is always true. I should've wrote that `selENd` appears in the query after the `UNION ALL` in `WHERE` line `and p.char_len + p.char_bgn <= :selEnd`.

If the declaration of `selEnd` is changed to `set selEnd [expr {799+1}]` then only the rows that should be returned are returned.

If this same query is run in the CLI or SQLite Fiddle using `.param set :selEnd 800` then `selEnd` is treated as an integer. If I just type `800` instead of `:selEnd` then the correct rows are returned.

If variable `SQL` is set using double quotes instead of braces and the condition is changed to use `$selEnd` insead of `:selEnd`, the correct rows are returned.

What am I not understanding that results in `:selEnd` being treated as `'800'` instead of `800` when using braces to set `SQL`?

I thought Tcl treated everything as a string until it was "used" for something. And `SQL` would simply be a string in which `selEnd` would be inserted as `800`; but, it appears that the use of `:selEnd`-type parameter substitution is deciding that `selEnd` is a string and should be inserted as `'800'`. Why?

Thank you.

```
set docId 1
set selStart 500
set selEnd 800; #[expr {799+1}]

set SQL {\
with recursive
pieces( order_idx, doc_id, key, buffer_id, char_start, char_len, char_bgn ) as
(
  select
     0,
     r.*,
     0
  from
    pt_pointers r
  where
        r.key = (select order_keys->>0 from ur_maps where doc_id = :docId)
    and r.doc_id = :docId

  UNION ALL

  select
     order_idx + 1,
     r.*,
     p.char_len + p.char_bgn
  from pt_pointers as r, pieces p
  where r.key = (select order_keys->>(order_idx+1) from ur_maps where doc_id = :docId)
    and p.char_len + p.char_bgn <= :selEnd
    and r.doc_id = :docId
)
select *
from pieces;\
}

db eval $SQL {
  chan puts stdout "$order_idx, $doc_id, $key, $buffer_id, $char_start, $char_len, $char_bgn"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked the question on the SQLite forum and [Dr. Hipp's answer](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/4b2d3977e1445649) is:

> In TCL, everything is a string, at least in theory. Under the hood,
> TCL keeps track of integers and floating point values and so forth.
> But the idea is that at the developer level, everything works as if it
> was a pure string. (And, indeed, prior to Tcl8.0, everything really
> was always a string. The other data types were introduced in Tcl8.0 as
> an optimization.)
>
> SQLite deviates from this idea that everything in TCL is a string.
> When binding, if the underlying TCL value has some representation
> other than string, SQLite tries to use that alternative represntation.
> This is technically a violation of the rules, for which I have been
> rebuked. But the design cannot be changed now without breaking
> compatibility, so it is what it is.
>
> Usually, the Tcl/SQLite interface "just works" without you the
> developer having to think about it. But if you get into some
> complicated situations, as you seem to have, then it never hurts to
> CAST your bindings

Comment: There are times you need to `CAST` with other language bindings too (especially when doing comparison operations, where it really matters).